# CSS strange thing happening when scaling

Tags: html, css, input

this is my first post here. I don't know how to explain my problem because I don't really know what is causing my CSS code to break. It would be easier to show you in a photo.

So I have a div tag and input and div child elements inslide. One of the div is static 32px x 32px and I am calculating its width with calc(100% - 32px), but when scaling some pixels aren't filled with the input.

Here's a photo of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HwaG.jpg

This occurs when the zoom is not divisible by 100. For example it breaks on 110%, 150% and 175%. But it is right when the zoom is 100%, 200%, 300%...

Heres my code:

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" value="Search" class="search-text" />
    <div class="search-icon" ></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search {
    height: 32px;
    width: 250px;
}
.search-text{
    float:left;
    width: calc(100% - 55px) !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    margin: 0;width: 196px;
}
.search-icon{
    display: inline-block !important;
    background-color: #ACB6BE;
    height: 30px;
    width: 31px;
    float:right;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #acb6be;
}
input[type=text] {
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #acb6be;
   min-width: 180px;
   color: #acb6be;
   padding: 0 10px;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-weight: 600;
}
```

Or jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39VDR/1/

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't be concerned with people who don't use default zoom. That is an edge case in terms of design

Comment: @mituw16 Yes, but I want perfection for my websites. Also my design is responsive so this problem may cause on mobile devices, tablets etc.

Comment: is the site perfect if its overloaded with unnecessary code?

Comment: And covered in `!important`s

Comment: I was trying to debug... Also, my input{...} CSS has some of these parameters, that's why I use !important. And aren't you supposed to help people here, not to attack them ?

Comment: @Andrey We're here to help but also to give advice. [Here is what your code gives us](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/39VDR/), it has a large space in between already. Thus, what you've given us is not enough for us to help you. Please provide enough code or a working example

Comment: @ZachSaucier Edited - http://jsfiddle.net/39VDR/1/

Comment: Your `!important` declarations can simply be replaced with higher specificity. `input[type="text"].search-text` will override `input[type="text"]`. http://jsfiddle.net/39VDR/2/. CSS is cascading, which means it looks at properties from top to bottom. Declaring `width: ... !important;` followed by `width ...;` is silly, as you can just reverse the order and drop the `!important` completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because when you zoom, your values will not be integer anymore. This means that rounding will take place and the outer container (`.search`) will be `1px` larger than you would expect.

You can remove the `float:right` on the `.search-icon` and it will work ok.

You can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/39VDR/4/

```
.search-icon{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ACB6BE;
    height: 30px;
    width: 31px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #acb6be;
    font-size:12px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Still, as mentioned, you can remove the `!important` if you just add more specificity to your selectors.